# Why is it necessary to review a question before posting it?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I just do not like the way that I have to first click on "review" and then "post". One can easily preview the question by scrolling up? I think Stack sites should revert to post directly.

Can't Stack sites do the filtering of low quality questions at the back end? I mean I click on "review", the site checks the question for any issue and if there isn't any, posts my question directly.

Comment: You want an answer, from volunteers, on a network that's provided to you free of charge. What's so wrong with putting a bit of extra effort into the question?

Answer (score 7):

Helping new users post better questions is... one of those things SE has been working on a while - and the review checks is a little less obvious to the end user than the [question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing).

One finds good questions come pre-reviewed. Folks spend a little extra time reading through and revising questions, ensuring that relevant information is available, hopefully in a usable form and so on.

The pre-posting review process just helps folks along here, and if you don't have any obvious issues, it's just an extra click. I *guess* it could pass you through if it passes, but I suspect being told your question is OK acts as positive reinforcement.

That said, there's always time to review - whether it's while writing a question, while posting or after posting, especially if it helps get a better outcome for solving your issue.