# Submitting a question directly when there is no feedback

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

Today John Chan [removed a very useful feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350782/361484). So now we are forced to see the review view again.

I honestly can't recall the last time the review view of the ask a question page yielded anything useful to me. Hence I was very glad I could skip it by simply pressing enter in the tags tab. Can we please have this functionality back, perhaps as a privilege?

Comment: meh, asking questions should be such a rare occurrence that a minor inconvenience, like being allowed to take one more look at your question before it is submitted, should be fine.

Comment: @user400654 I guess that depends. I quite often post a question here on MSE, which are generally speaking pretty well accepted. If there was any useful feedback on that screen I'd welcome it, but that is (at least for me) not the case in 99% of the time.

Comment: @Luuklag https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258136/how-do-i-write-a-good-feature-request

Comment: The developer didn't "remove" a feature, he "fixed" an anomaly in the system.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the possibility of submitting a question without a review was a **bug** not a *feature* and the bug is now gone for good.

There is no harm in having a review process check our questions. Spending just a few extra seconds for another click is nothing compared to the time the community will spend in answering our questions. Can't we have this minor inconvenience for the sake of the community? Also, in [Journeyman Geek's words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349823/771581),

> being told your question is OK acts as positive reinforcement.

Thus, this should not even be a privilege for high rep users. An extra check is always good; after all, mistakes can be made by anyone.